# differentiable and sequences of functions

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, sequence-of-function

Let $f_n:(a,b)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable and $f_n\rightarrow f$.

Can $f$ be differentiated?

Would it be  $f'(x_0)=\lim_{n \to \infty}f_n'(x_0)$ for $x_0\in (a,b)$ ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rudin 7.17 PMA question on cauchy criterion of uniform convergence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4158419/rudin-7-17-pma-question-on-cauchy-criterion-of-uniform-convergence)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can $f$ be differentiated?

Not necessarily. Consider $f_n(x) = \sqrt{x^2 + \frac{1}{n}}$ on $(-a, a)$. $f_n(x) \to f (x) = |x|$ which is not differentiable at $0$.

> Would it be $f'(x_0)= \lim_{n\to\infty} f_n'(x_0)$ for $x_0 \in (a,b)$ ?

Not necessarily. Let $f_n(x) = \frac{\sin(nx)}{\sqrt{n}}, n \ge 1$ for $x\in(-a, a)$ where $a > 0$.

$f_n \to f = 0$.

So, $f'(x) = 0$ for all $x\in(-a, a)$. $f_n'(x) = \sqrt{n}\cos(nx)$. However, $f_n'(0) = \sqrt{n} \to \infty$ but $f'(0) = 0$.

Comment: Thank you very much. @fwd

Comment: I think the convergence here is punctuate, do you think so? @fwd

Answer (score 0):

For the supremum norm, this is not true in general. You are trying to change the order of limits (in the sequence and in the derivative) which generally changes the result. For example, consider a sequence of differentiable functions that tend towards an indicator function of a set. The limit is not differentiable. If you have studied Fourier series you can generate similar examples to any integrable function.

If you define a different norm, say where you take the supremum plus the supremum of the first derivative, then you would have convergence, and there are other examples of norms where you do get convergence to some notion of a derivative.

Comment: Thank you @user2271513

Answer (score 0):

No.

You need a stronger assumption that ${f_n'}$ converges uniformly on (a b).

Neither ${f_n}$ --> f pointwise on (a b), nor ${f_n}$ --> f uniformly on (a b) is good enough (See Example 7.5 a counter example) for the result to hold.

See W. Rudin, PMA, Theorem 7.17 for under what condition, the result is true.